# Convert Qlikview Hex Date to Normal Date

Tags: excel, hex, powerquery, qlikview, qliksense

I exported a XML file from Qlikview and the dates are in this 16-letter/digits form (i.e. 40E5A40D641FDB97). I have tried multiple ways to convert it to floating decimals and then dates but all methods have failed (incl. Excel HEX2DEC).

Anyone has dealt with this issue before? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What have you tried?  HEX2DEC won't work since it will not handle numbers that large, but there are plenty of options posted in this forum and elsewhere for converting large hex numbers. What date is it supposed to represent?  I think qlikview stores dates similar to excel (days since 30 Dec 1899.

Comment: FYI, there is an Excel Addin called [xNumbers](https://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm) which can do decimal conversion of Hexnumbers.  Applying that to your hex number and formatting the result as a date/time `=> 04-May-2021 10:02:36`  **xNumbers** hasn't been updated in some time.  In newer versions of Excel, it seem to be responsible for an extra Excel instance opening when you start up.  But the code is open source so you might be able to extract what you want.

Comment: I've been reading round this and trying to understand how conversion to floating point numbers from hex representation works. V. impressed that @Ron has come up with a result for conversion of your example to a date - would be interested to know if that was the result you expected so I can maybe reproduce it.

Comment: @TomSharpe My logic: I believe Qlikview encodes dates the same as Excel (although not sure about 2/29/1900). So that hex number only makes sense if it is a floating point value and not an integer.  Translating the Hex that way returns a serial date/time that seems reasonable.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you for the inputs but it seems like the xnumber Add-In is no longer available (at least on the laptop that I am using). I have tried a couple of other codes posted by the rest on powerBI & this forum but none seems to translate the date into the correct number (they return result like 1.2319E+164 which is way too big to convert to date). How can I make hex return a floating point value? Thank you!

Comment: @TomSharpe thanks for the input, just to list some examples, 40E5A4C790061172
 should return 10/5/2021  5:40:19 am; 40E5A478A375F31B
 returns 7/5/2021  6:28:44 pm; currently only this site that I tried returns the correct return, https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/, any advise how I can move forward from here? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "*not available on your laptop*"?  Is that site blocked for you? If so, perhaps using a VPN might help.  Or download the add-in on another machine, and then copy it over to yours.

Answer (score 1):

[This reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) shows how floating point numbers are represented. In double precision (using a total of 64 bits) there is a sign bit, 11-bit exponent and 53-bit significand or mantissa. Observant readers will notice that gives a total of 65 bits: this is because the most significant bit in the mantissa is a *hidden bit* which by convention is always set to 1 and does not have to be stored.

Taking the first example:

[image]

we have

*Exponent*

[image]

The exponent is the first three hexadecimal digits (sign bit plus 11 digits - but the sign bit will always be zero for dates since they are positive numbers). It can be converted using any suitable standard method e.g. in Excel 365:

```
=LET(L,LEN(A2),seq,SEQUENCE(L),SUM((FIND(MID(A2,seq,1),"0123456789ABCDEF")-1)*16^(L-seq)))
```

The correct result is obtained by subtracting 1023 (the offset) from the converted value e.g.

40E -> 1038

1038 - 1023 -> 15

So the multiplier is 2^15.

*Significand*

[image]

We need to take the right-hand 13 hexadecimal digits (52 bits) of the string and convert it to a fraction using whatever is your favourite conversion method e.g. in Excel 365:

```
=LET(L,LEN(A2),seq,SEQUENCE(L),SUM((FIND(MID(A2,seq,1),"0123456789ABCDEF")-1)*16^(-seq)))
```

Then you need to add 1 (this is the hidden bit which is always set to 1).

*Putting this together:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Power Query routine that will convert that Hex number into its Date Equivalent:

I generate the binary equivalent of the Hex number using a lookup table and concatenating the results.

The algorithm should be clear in the coding, and it follows the rules set out in IEEE-754.

For the dates you mention in your question, it provides the same results.

Note that this routine assumes a valid value encoded as you describe your date representations from Qlikview.  It is not a general purpose routine.

```
let 

//don't really need the Decimal column
hexConvTable = Table.FromRecords({
    [Hex="0", Dec=0,  Bin = "0000"],
    [Hex="1", Dec=1,  Bin = "0001"],
    [Hex="2", Dec=2,  Bin = "0010"],
    [Hex="3", Dec=3,  Bin = "0011"],
    [Hex="4", Dec=4,  Bin = "0100"],
    [Hex="5", Dec=5,  Bin = "0101"],
    [Hex="6", Dec=6,  Bin = "0110"],
    [Hex="7", Dec=7,  Bin = "0111"],
    [Hex="8", Dec=8,  Bin = "1000"],
    [Hex="9", Dec=9,  Bin = "1001"],
    [Hex="A", Dec=10, Bin = "1010"],
    [Hex="B", Dec=11, Bin = "1011"],
    [Hex="C", Dec=12, Bin = "1100"],
    [Hex="D", Dec=13, Bin = "1101"],
    [Hex="E", Dec=14, Bin = "1110"],
    [Hex="F", Dec=15, Bin = "1111"]},
            type table[Hex = Text.Type, Dec = Int64.Type, Bin = Text.Type]),

    hexUp = Text.Upper(hexNum),
    hexSplit = Table.FromList(Text.ToList(hexUp),Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"hexNum"}),

//To sort back to original order
    addIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(hexSplit,"Index",0,1,Int64.Type),

//combine with conversion table
    binConv =   Table.Sort(
                    Table.Join(
                        addIndex,"hexNum",hexConvTable,"Hex",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
                    {"Index", Order.Ascending}),

//equivalent binary
    binText = Text.Combine(binConv[Bin]),
    sign = Text.Start(binText,1),

//change exponent binary parts to numbers
    expBin = List.Transform(Text.ToList(Text.Middle(binText,1,11)),Number.FromText),

//exponent bias will vary depending on the precision being used
expBias = 1023, //Number.Power(2,10-List.PositionOf(expBin,1))-1,

    expPwr= List.Reverse({0..10}),
    exp = List.Accumulate({0..10},0,(state, current) =>
            state + (expBin){current} * Number.Power(2,expPwr{current})) - expBias,

    mantBin = List.Transform(Text.ToList(Text.Middle(binText,11,52)),Number.FromText),
    mantPwr = {0..51},
    mant = List.Accumulate({0..51},0,(state, current) =>
            state + (mantBin){current} / Number.Power(2,mantPwr{current})) +1,
    dt = mant * Number.Power(2,exp)
in 
   DateTime.From(dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use standard windows formatting with Num# (convert text to number) and Num to convert from hex to bin in Qlikview :

```
# example data from inline table in loading script
[our_hex_numbers]:
LOAD
 Num(Num#(hex,'(HEX)'),'(BIN)') as bin
Inline
[hex,
'A',
'B',
'C'];
```

here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a report on QlikView licenses for myself using the file CalData.pgo.xml

and I ran into a non - critical problem of converting hex to date .. but without this transformation, the report would not be complete. ‌‌ (LastUsed, ToBeDeleted)
In general, I was looking for it, but I didn't find anything useful right away, except for converting 13x hex to excel.
But in the file CalData.pgo.xml the date is set in 16 digits, not 13.. I did not understand how to adapt the excel formula for 16 digits, but I realized that it is possible to trim a 16-bit hex to 13 digits. and it seems that nothing significant is lost at the same time .
it works fine for me
=date((num(Num#(right([PerDocumentCalData/NamedCalsAllocated/CalAllocEntry.LastUsed],13),'(HEX)') )*pow(16,-13)+1)*Pow(2,15),'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30516712)